# How to determine pitch and roll of a rectangle knowing $(x,y,z)$ corner points?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

So let's say I have a rectangle with four corner points, and that I know the $(x,y,z)$ position of each point. How would I go about finding the pitch and roll of that rectangle?

[image]

Comment: Relevant: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html

Comment: Also:L you need to decide whether the pitch transformation is applied before or after the roll transformation. And you also might have to include a yaw transformation...

Comment: What are the two directions? And as above, the order maters?

Comment: How you avoid Yaw? It has impact as well. What is your reference?

Comment: Well I didn't need to know yaw; I didn't realize it impacted pitch and roll. Reference is the ground plane.